# Rendering PDF in UIWebView iOS 8, causes a black border around PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

In iOS 8, when rendering a .PDF into a `UIWebview` there is a black border and background around the PDF displayed (not the whole background view).  Note this is not the UIWebview background which is set to:

```
myWebView.opaque = NO;
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This is not present in < iOS8,  (no black bordering coloured background around the .PDF)

Anyone else experienced this who could shed some light on this?

Im loading my PDF into the Web view like so..

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (self.pdfData != nil && self.viewHasUnloaded == YES) {
        self.viewHasUnloaded = NO;
        [self.webView loadData:self.pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be no longer happening for me with iOS8.3

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turn off WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled and the black border goes away:

In applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions add the following lines:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Brilliant and simple!

Answer (score 35):

After a bit of investigating the issue I managed to understand where the problem is. So the `UIWebView` is an `UIView`, with an `UIScrollView` (with private class `_UIWebViewScrollView`) as subview. The loading of a PDF into the `UIWebView` goes under the following flow:
**1)** `UIWebView` starts loading the request. By this time `-webViewDidStartLoad:` delegate method is called.
**2)** After the PDF is (down)loaded the delegate method `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called. By that time the `UIWebView` knows this is a PDF file and a subview with a private class `UIWebPDFView` is already inserted into the `_UIWebViewScrollView`, but the PDF itself is not rendered, yet.
And here comes the problem.
**3)** The PDF is rendered offscreen and after it's ready a new subview with private class `UIPDFPageView` is inserted into `UIWebPDFView` and the PDF is displayed. The problem is when this insertion happens the `UIWebPDFView` has its `backgroundColor` set to black and this insertion happens after the `-webViewDidFinishLoad:` is called (the time depends on how big the PDF is to render). That's why it's **not** a good solution to go through all subviews of the `UIWebView` and set their `backgroundColor` property to white, for example.
The good news is that the `UIViewController`'s method `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called when the `UIPDFPageView` is inserted into the `UIWebView`'s view hierarchy. So, in the end the solution is to have this objective-C code into our view controller:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // Assuming self.webView is our UIWebView
    // We go though all sub views of the UIWebView and set their backgroundColor to white
    UIView *v = self.webView;
    while (v) {
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        v = [v.subviews firstObject];
    }
}
```

And in Swift:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    var v:UIView? = self.webView
    while (v != nil) {
        v!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        v = v!.subviews.first
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get black background with the PDF with this solution, the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called, however it makes no difference? Ive tried changing `[v.subviews firstObject]`to `[v.subviews lastObject]` and still the same for me

Comment: It's working correctly in my tests. Try to NSLog(@"%@", v); inside the while and see if the last time it's called you will have the `UIPDFPageView`.

Comment: Hmmm im getting (null) there `NSLog(@"%@", v);`

Comment: Are you sure your `self.webView` `IBOutlet` is connected?

Comment: Positive yes,web view is connected

Comment: Can you paste the console logs if you put the `NSLog(@"%@", v);` just above the `v.backgroundColor = ...`?

Comment: Yep(NSLog(@"PDF VIEW%@", v);), I get PDF VIEW <UIWebView: 0x14d0ed10; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x14d0e0f0>>
2014-09-17 15:08:53.035 iCertifi[474:47921] PDF VIEW <_UIWebViewScrollView: 0x14df9b10; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14dfa060>; layer = <CALayer: 0x14df9e90>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>
2014-09-17 15:08:53.035 iCertifi[474:47921] PDF VIEW <UIWebBrowserView: 0x15a17c00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14dd1c70>; layer = <UIWebLayer: 0x14df3880>>

Comment: There's a small difference in the view hierarchy when loading local pdf and remote pdf, but in the both cases I get the correct behaviour - without the black border. Can you show the code on how you load the pdf in your question. It might help investigating/replicating the behaviour you have.

Comment: Okay I think we might be talking about different borders. The answer I have you was about a bug in the web view in iOS 8 where it puts a big black border around the pdf. I think you might be talking about the thin border with the shadow. If that's the case, under `v.backgrounColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` add the lines:     v.layer.borderWidth = 0.; v.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.;

Comment: No its a solid black background around and behind the PDF, the border and shadow you mentioned is hidden by the black background.   I guess will have to wait for an update in iOS8.  Appreciate the help though, have upvoted you

Comment: Works a treat for me.

Comment: Not getting NULL, but when I log v I am not getting a UIPDFPageView. Web view definitely connected - because the PDF is loading. But as such, the black border is still present. Any ideas??

Comment: Works great for me! I am using it in a pop-over controller on an iPad app.

Comment: @graver: You code is work for me, but when i load the PDF in webview its shows with the black border , it is work when I rotate device to another orientation. In short pdf load in webview first time it is with black border, but rotate device to another orientation then issue is fixed. Can you help me on this ??

Comment: @Divya Bhalodiya Same here. Any solution!?

Comment: This works for me UIView *v = self.webView.scrollView;
    while (v) {
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        v = [v.subviews firstObject];
    }  *Note looping through scrollView subviews

Answer (score 9):

I assume it's a bit of a timing-thing because `UIWebPDFView` is added as subview not until the rendering has finished and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called before that happens. And because there is no event like didFinshedRendering i used a timer to check when `UIWebPDFView` is added.

The following is working for me.

Put a instance variable in the in the header file or your class:

```
// instance variable for interval timer
NSTimer *BackgroundIntervalTimer;
```

Put these methods in the implementation file:

```
- (void)startUIWebViewBackgroundFixTimer {
    // if > iOS 8 start fixing background color of UIWebPDFView
    if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
        // hide pdfWebView until background fixed
        self.pdfWebView.alpha = 0.0;
        // start interval timer
        BackgroundIntervalTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1  target:self selector:@selector(fixBackground) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void)stopUIWebViewBackgroundFixTimer {
    [BackgroundIntervalTimer invalidate];
    BackgroundIntervalTimer = nil;
}

- (void)fixBackground {
    // stop timer interval
    [self stopUIWebViewBackgroundFixTimer];

    // Assuming self.webView is our UIWebView
    // We go though all sub views of the UIWebView and set their backgroundColor to white
    UIView *v = self.pdfWebView;
    while (v) {
        //v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        v = [v.subviews firstObject];

        if ([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebPDFView"]) {
            [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

            // background set to white so fade view in and exit
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                             animations:^{
                                 self.pdfWebView.alpha = 1.0;
                             }
                             completion:nil];
            return;
        }
    }
    // UIWebPDFView doesnt exist yet so exit and try later
    [self startUIWebViewBackgroundFixTimer];
}
```

Now put this line right after the line where you load the pdf:

```
// if iOS 8 check if pdfWebView got subview of class UIWebPDFView
[self startUIWebViewBackgroundFixTimer];
```

Hints:

- `SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN` is a macro to enshure the code is only execuded on iOS 8 and above.
- `self.pdfWebView` is your UIWebView.

Comment: Update, not sure if this is due to iOS V8.02, this solution does not work constantly now...back to the drawing board!

Comment: I've tested the code with iOS 8.0.2 the time it was released and found no problems since then, code works as expected. Will check again with 8.1, hopefully this fix will no longer be needed then.

Comment: For me now, it doesn't work the first time view is loaded, and then works randomly other time.  I agree hopefully it will be fixed asap

Comment: Try to add the fix into the webViewDidFinishLoad-Method also:

`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView  
{  
    // just in case...  
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {  
        // hide pdfWebView until background fixed  
        [self performSelector:@selector(fixBackground)     withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];  
    }  
}`

Answer (score 6):

The solution is here:

**EDIT** (link Broken)

[<del>How to remove black border from PDF/UIWebView in iOS 8</del>](http://technopote.com/how-to-remove-black-border-from-pdfuiwebview-in-ios-8/)

It worked for me.

The trick is to change the background color after webView finish loading.

**EDIT**

> In iOS 8.0, if you are loading a PDF page in UIWebView then you will
>   get the black border around the page.
>
> When you load PDF in to webview then it insert UIWebPDFView into
>   webview.
>
> When PDF is rendered it add a new private class UIPDFPageView into
>   UIWebPDFView which have a black background color. This all insertion
>   happens after the  -webViewDidFinishLoad: method called. So you need
>   to set clear or white background color set after the
>   -webViewDidFinishLoad: method
>
> Add the following method for remove the black border color
>
> Call the function in -webViewDidFinishLoad:
>
> ```
> if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
>     [self performSelector:@selector(clearBackground) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
> }
> ```
>
> .
>
> ```
> - (void)clearBackground {
>     UIView *v = webVw;
>     while (v) {
>         //v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>         v = [v.subviews firstObject];
>
>         if ([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebPDFView"]) {
>             [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
>
>             // background set to white so fade view in and exit
>             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
>                              animations:^{
>                                  webVw.alpha = 1.0;
>                              }
>                              completion:nil];
>             return;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thnx, worked for me, I replaced the performSelector stuff with dispatch_after to keep this ugly solution as minimal as possible :-)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Xamarin, a variation of gravers solution worked once translated to C#.

Place the following in the UIViewController:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

        var subViews = webView.Subviews;
        foreach (UIView v in subViews) {
            v.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

            var subv = v.Subviews;
            foreach (UIView w in subv) {
                w.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made the answer in Swift. Feel free to use:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var view :UIView?
    view = PdfView as UIView
    while (view != nil) {
        view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        view = view?.subviews.first as? UIView
    }
}
```

PDFView is the name of my UIWebView.

Answer (score 2):

This is railwayparade's implementation in Swift:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(false, forKey: "WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem..Unable to fix it using the suggested solution i have also tried setting the back ground color in webViewDidFinishLoad delegate fucntion but of no use..

NSLog content :

```
-[TextualWebView webViewDidFinishLoad:](LNo.:141) PDF VIEW< UIWebView: 0x1c5ec6d0;  
frame = (36 41; 637 810); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = < CALayer: 0x1c5ec740>>

-[TextualWebView webViewDidFinishLoad:](LNo.:141) PDF VIEW<_UIWebViewScrollView: 0x1c5f0070;  
 frame = (0 0; 637 810); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c5f02d0>;   
 layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5ef6f0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {637, 810}>

-[TextualWebView webViewDidFinishLoad:](LNo.:141) PDF VIEW< UIWebPDFView: 0x1c6e6320;  
 frame = (0 0; 637 810); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1c6e0330>;  
 layer = < CALayer: 0x1c6e6410>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a mix of [Heiko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25995976/404321) and [gravers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25889696/404321) answers.

The view responsible for the black background is an instance of UIWebPDFView. So we can use gravers' approach, but without making every UIWebView subview white (which will mess the pages indicator).

Also, this solution makes no assumption on the `UIWebPDFView` position in the view hierarchy.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self fixWebviewBackground:self.webView];
}

- (void)fixWebviewBackground:(UIView *)view
{
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebPDFView"]) {
        view.backgroundColor = nil;
        return;
    }
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        [self fixWebviewBackground:subview];
    }
}
```

We recursively descend on all subviews, changing only the UIWebPDFView's backgroundColor.

Comment: That simply does not work for me.  Both methods being called, no difference to final result

Comment: @JSA986 Well, it depends on when you load your PDF data into the UIWebView. You'll need to call `fixWebviewBackground:` only **after** you UIWebView finished rendering the PDF for the first time.

Comment: The code is added AFTER data loaded - still nothing

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, plus I was trying to zoom into my pdf after it had loaded. If this code was called prematurely it would render the pdf un-useable - you could not pan/scroll the pdf at all, you could still pinch to zoom but it only zoomed into the very top-left corner.

I initially had some code to remove the black border and zoom into the pdf after a given delay like so;

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self performSelector:@selector(zoomIntoPDF) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];
}
```

The 0.6s delay is useless though. It would (sometimes) still not be long enough when testing on an (in use) iPhone 4S. On the latest devices, a 0.6s hit in performance is ridiculous when it worked with a <0.05s delay.

---

@graver's solution helped me to investigate the issue. As suggested I was running `NSLog(@"%@", v);` in the while loop (I was also running `NSLog(@"-------------");` before the while loop).

I was also calling `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after a delay of 0.6s like so;

```
[self performSelector:@selector(viewDidLayoutSubviews) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];
```

These are my logs:

```
-------------
<UIWebView: 0x7fd803c2e920; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803c18290>>
<_UIWebViewScrollView: 0x7fd803f6a720; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd803f6afb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803f6a660>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>
<UIWebBrowserView: 0x7fd80487b400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd803f65290>; layer = <UIWebLayer: 0x7fd803da2050>>
-------------
<UIWebView: 0x7fd803c2e920; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803c18290>>
<_UIWebViewScrollView: 0x7fd803f6a720; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd803f6afb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803f6a660>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>
<UIWebBrowserView: 0x7fd80487b400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd803f65290>; layer = <UIWebLayer: 0x7fd803da2050>>
Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
-------------
<UIWebView: 0x7fd803c2e920; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803c18290>>
<_UIWebViewScrollView: 0x7fd803f6a720; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd803f6afb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803f6a660>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 273.14641744548288}>
<UIWebPDFView: 0x7fd803c02570; frame = (0 0; 320 273.146); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd803c239d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803c16a70>>
<UIPDFPageView: 0x7fd80601cf60; frame = (0 7; 320 259); tag = 1000000; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fd803c27db0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fd803ddd2f0>>
```

As you can see, `UIPDFPageView` does not appear until right at the end - the third and final time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was called from the delay.

---

**EDIT:** This is a very similar principle to @Heiko's answer but uses a recursive method rather than a timer.

There must be a better solution, such as detecting a change in the `webViews` subviews, but this solution works for now:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    loopCap = 0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(hasPDFLoaded) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];
}

- (void)hasPDFLoaded
{
    BOOL containsPDF = NO;
    for (UIView *child in self.webView.scrollView.subviews)
    {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([child class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebPDFView"]) {
            containsPDF = YES;
        }
    }
    if (containsPDF) {
        [self fixWebviewAndZoom];
    } else {
        if (loopCap < 20) {
            loopCap++;
            [self performSelector:@selector(hasPDFLoaded) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];
        }
    }
}

-(void)fixWebviewAndZoom {
    UIView *v = self.webView;
    while (v) {
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        v = [v.subviews firstObject];
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(zoomIntoPDF) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.05];
}
```

*Please excuse the method and variable names, I will come up with more appropriate ones tomorrow!*

As you can see, it is a recursive method which calls itself until the pdf has loaded. There is a cap to avoid any infinite loops (there should be an alert or something if it has not loaded in this time). The cap is 20 and the delay is 0.05s which allows 1 second for the pdf to load. I will probably increase the cap to 40, but I think 0.05 is ok performance wise, but I need to conduct some proper testing.

I hope this has been insightful, but I'd really appreciate some feedback or improvements to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but not so ideal fix is to add a border around the UIWebView of the same color as your pdf document's background color. This will prevent the ugliness to some extent until Apple fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the background color of the subviews of the UIWebView after the PDF finishes loading -- the essence of most of the answers above -- works for me. However, I've found that since iOS 5, webViewDidFinishLoad is called before the web view actually finishes loading, so I've been doing this to avoid various problems in my apps:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)documentView {
    [self performSelector:@selector(webViewDidReallyFinishLoad:) withObject:documentView afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void)webViewDidReallyFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)documentView {
    // now we can restore the transparency
}
```

The misleading behavior of webViewDidFinishLoad might explain why this approach isn't working for some people.

Another consequence of this behavior is that webView.scrollView.contentSize is not yet set when webViewDidFinishLoad is called. I submitted this to Apple as bug 10259756 in October 2011, but they closed the bug report with a status of "Behaves correctly."