# Black border around PDF in UIWebView, how to remove with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am writing an IOS8 app in Swift. I am getting a black border around my PDF when it loads in UIWebView. There is a [write up](http://technopote.com/how-to-remove-black-border-from-pdfuiwebview-in-ios-8/) on how to fix it, but I have struggled with converting this into Swift. Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true      
    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(myArray[0], ofType: "pdf")!)        
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

And here is the objective C code from [this link](http://technopote.com/how-to-remove-black-border-from-pdfuiwebview-in-ios-8/) that is supposed to fix the black border issue. This goes in webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
[self performSelector:@selector(clearBackground) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];}
```

And this is the function it calls:

```
- (void)clearBackground {
UIView *v = webVw;
while (v) {
    //v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    v = [v.subviews firstObject];

    if ([NSStringFromClass([v class]) isEqualToString:@"UIWebPDFView"]) {
        [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        // background set to white so fade view in and exit
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             webVw.alpha = 1.0;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
        return;
    }
}  }
```

I have almost no experience with objective C, and I'm not sure even where to start converting this to Swift. If I could just be pointed in the right direction on converting this, or if anyone has written a Swift app with code that fixes this issue that they would let me use, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. First time posting here.

Comment: @beefjerky8805 welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question to include the swift code that you tried to write, and highlight which line of code is not working. If there are multiple lines of code that don't work, then ask a separate question for each one (probably wait for the first question to be answered before asking the other questions).

Comment: Thanks. I edited to include the code that i would like to use, but I'm honestly not sure how to start with it. If someone could give me a few tips on how to go about converting it, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your suggested solution is not enough even in Objective-C.
Please see [Rendering PDF in UIWebView iOS 8, causes a black border around PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813551/).

And , I fixed this issue in Swift.
Put below code into the main UIViewController.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    clearPDFBackground(self.webView)
}

func clearPDFBackground(webView: UIWebView) {
    var view :UIView?
    view = webView as UIView

    while view? != nil {
        if NSStringFromClass(view?.dynamicType) == "UIWebPDFView" {
            view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        }

        view = view?.subviews.first as UIView?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works - kind of. When the view first loads, I still get the black border, but if I do anything to change the view, such as tap to hide the bars, or double tap to zoom in, or rotate the simulator, then the black border disappears for good.

Comment: Ah! I did not have my constraints configured properly. Your solution works great now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @beefjerky8805 I have the same problem you had. It still shows black for the first load. What is it you did to fix that?

Comment: I'm sorry it has taken me so long to respond, you've probably fixed it by now. My problem was simply that I somehow didn't have any constraints assigned to the webview, and it was assigning automatic ones. I don't really understand it enough to explain it in more detail than that. Anyway, I added 4 constraints: trailing space to superview = -24, leading space to superview = -24, bottom space to superview = 0, top space to top layout = -5. I also checked the option in the bottom toolbar which allows the pdf to be behind the bottom toolbar, as my pdf's are too tall for the view. Hope this helps.