# iOS remove shadow from UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to remove the shadow around a UIWebView that loads and displays a .pdf file. I have tried to implement solutions posted between 2010 and 2013 with no success. Solutions I tried include:

```
self.contentWebView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    for (UIView* view in self.contentWebView.subviews)
    {
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
    }

    for (UIView* shadowView in [self.contentWebView.scrollView subviews])
    {
        if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [shadowView setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Possible [duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813551/rendering-pdf-in-uiwebview-ios-8-causes-a-black-border-around-pdf)? Lots of solutions but most recent is:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"WebKitDiskImageCacheEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Older one with more votes is:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // Assuming self.webView is our UIWebView
    // We go though all sub views of the UIWebView and set their backgroundColor to white
    UIView *v = self.webView;
    while (v) {
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        v = [v.subviews firstObject];
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this fixes the black border around a UIWebView when loading a .pdf. I am talking about the default shadow every UIWebView has.