# iOS WKWebview load local PDF Files some pages become black

Tags: ios, pdf, wkwebview

I user wkwebview to load a local pdf file and it works fine. But when I scroll up and down to some pages, some pages become black. Have you also come across this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

Assuming you are implementing WKNavigationDelegate (YourWebView.navigationDelegate) in your ViewController.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation 
{
   UIView *v = webView;
    while (v) {
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        v = [v.subviews firstObject];
    }
}
```

For reference: [Rendering PDF in UIWebView iOS 8, causes a black border around PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813551/rendering-pdf-in-uiwebview-ios-8-causes-a-black-border-around-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 11.0+ use `PDFView` (also see [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit)) to display a `PDF`. `PDFView` does not have the issue with black pages.